# Shapefile write protect not using Microsoft?

Tags: shapefile, password

I need to send a file to a client which can't be edited or exported. It should be write protected using a password. Is there any way to do this with a shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

The question previously had an ArcGIS desktop tag. If the OP has ArcGIS with a publisher license, it is possible to output data to be read in ArcReader. Publisher gives the option to password protect the data and prevent printing, export and some other options I believe. The drawback is that it is not possible to use this data elsewhere. [ArcGIS Publisher page.](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/publisher/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible with a shapefile.
The only thing you can do is set the file as read-only using Windows (as in the answer to [Making shapefile Read-Only to ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127081/arcgis-10-2-shp-file-read-only)), but the client would still be able to edit or export the data if they wanted to.

If the client only needs to view the data, not edit or export, your best option might be a PDF.